# Adding special character at several places in a string in perl script

Tags: perl, perl-module

I read some raw data from my device. This data contains the IP address as well but in a different format. As you know the IP address is generally written in the format a.b.c.d. However I have data of the format abcd given from the device. I need to get this in the format a.b.c.d How do I do this in a perl script?

Regards

Comment: you can use the [`unpack` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) to transform binary data to Perl scalars. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Please show an example of the IP addresses coming from the device.

Comment: My code is something of the sort: print $string; The output of which is something like c0a80001. I would like to make $string to contains c0.a8.00.01. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways.  This inserts dots with substring.

map { substr($string,$_,0)='.' } (6,4,2);

Maybe you prefer regexes.

$string =~ s/[0-9a-f]{2}\K(?!\Z)/./g;

Answer (score 0):

First, let us split the hex string into substrings of two characters:

```
... split /..\K/, "c0a80001";
```

We treat each fragment as a hex string, and get the numeric value with the `hex` builtin:

```
... map hex, ...
```

Then, we join all numbers with a period:

```
join '.', ...
```

Combined:

```
my $ip = join '.', map hex, split /..\K/, "c0a80001";
print "$ip\n";
```

Output: `192.168.0.1`. This is the usual text representation for an IPv4 address.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on the approach taken, but mostly you would need to escape with a backslash the dot from the IP address

```
a\.b\.c\.d
```

Some source code with be nice btw ...

Comment: My code is something of the sort:                                       print $string; The output of which is something like c0a80001. I would like to make $string to contains c0.a8.00.01. How do I do this?